# how to given data in serial port

Tags: serial-port

```
d_key_events_mapped = {
    'Start Case': 's',
    'Alarm': 'a',
    'Checkout': 'c',
    'Endcase': 'e',
    'Shutdown': 'F12',
    'Procedure': 'p',
    'Audio': 's',
    'Trends': 't',
    'Screen setup': 'u',
    'System setup': 'w',
    'Spirometry': 'y',
    'Auto': 'y',
    'Vent': 'v',
    'TV': 'F2'
}
```

Create one dic{} for Action presskey function the input was given to serial port.then if i press key 'a' in keyboard that shows alarm i want this type of program? given solution for me

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to [edit] and tag a language. You should also add your current attempt and an explanation of what the issue is. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].